# Runtime error 424: Object Required

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I made a huge mistake trying to bullet-proof something and accidentally saved over working code and don't know what I did wrong!

Here's the pertinent code:

```
Option Base 1
Dim userRange() as Range
Dim sheetCount as Integer
```

... (Code to determine "sheetCount" as defined by user here)...

```
ReDim userRange(sheetCount)
Dim r As Integer
For r = 1 To sheetCount
    Sheets(r).Select
    Debug.Print VBA.TypeName(userRange)
    Debug.Print VBA.TypeName(userRange())
    Debug.Print VBA.TypeName(userRange(r))
    Set userRange(r) = Application.InputBox( _
        Prompt:="Select a range to import.", _
        Title:="Select range # " & r, _
        Default:=currentsheet.Range("A1").Address, _
        Type:=8)
```

The line that throws the error is **Set userRange(r)...** Why won't VBA recognize userRange(r) as an object? The Immediate window prints:

```
Object()
Object()
Nothing
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

JSR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with `userRange`. You have no variable named `currentSheet`. Since you used `Sheets(r).Select`, you likely meant the object `ActiveSheet` instead. I recommend always using `Option Explicit`.

Comment: <3 :-) I *did* have ActiveSheet before, which I replaced with a variable in an effort to limit the number of sheets the loop could access (or attempt to anyway!). When I decided to scrap the idea, I missed an instance of the variable. Thanks very much!